# Change of (orthonormal) basis.

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

As I see it, the author says that $[Tv]_{e} = A[v]_{e}$ in the last paragraph. How do I see that ?

[image]

I think I've jusitied the first entry in $[Tv]_{e} = A[v]_{e}$ as follows

\begin{align*}
\langle \text{T}v,e_{1}\rangle &= \langle \text{T}e_{1},e_{1}\rangle\langle v,e_{1}\rangle + \cdots + \langle \text{T}e_{n},e_{1}\rangle\langle v,e_{n}\rangle\\
&=\langle\langle \text{T}e_{1},e_{1}\rangle v,e_{1}\rangle\rangle\\
&=\langle \text{T}v,e_{1}\rangle.
\end{align*}

Is there any other way to see it, or interpret it ?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is this - there is a correspondence between matrices in $\mathbb{F}^{n\times n}$ and linear operators in $\mathcal{L}(V,V)$.

To every linear operator $T\in \mathcal{L}(V,V)$ one can associate a matrix as follows : Pick a basis $\mathcal{B} = \{e_i\}$ of $V$, and consider the matrix $T_{\mathcal{B}}$ whose columns are the vectors $\{T(e_i)\}$.

Clearly, this depends on the choice of basis, so the question is : if we choose a different basis $\mathcal{B}'$, then how are the two matrices $T_{\mathcal{B}}$ and $T_{\mathcal{B}'}$ related?

The answer is : There is an invertible matrix $P$ such that
$$
T_{\mathcal{B}'} = PT_{\mathcal{B}}P^{-1}
$$

Comment: Yes I'm familiar with this diagonalization. My first thought was that A actually is the product that you wrote ind the end. I think that the author just make the statement that T$[v]_{e}=$A$[v]_{e}$ without justifying it.