# Notation for vector v in basis x, dimension y

Tags: vector-spaces, notation

What is common notation for the value of the $n$th dimension of vector $v$, given by basis $x$. Is it something like $$v_{x}^{y}$$

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The $n$th (or $y$th) dimension of vector $v$" is not a phrase I'm familiar with. As such, I assume you meant the same thing as "the $n$th component of a vector in $\mathbb R^{m}$ (or similar).

This may depend on your textbook, but as you can see in places like [Change of (orthonormal) basis.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523502/change-of-orthonormal-basis), one notation (which I've seen a few books use) for the $i$th component of the vector $\mathbf v$ when written in terms of an ordered basis $\mathcal B$ would be $$\left([\mathbf v]_\mathcal B\right)_i$$

If the parentheses get in your way, I imagine it would be clear (especially if you explain your notation) to write something like $[\mathbf v]^\mathcal B_i$ or perhaps even $\mathbf v^\mathcal B_i$ if you're using a convention (like I'm using `\mathcal`) that makes it clear at a glance that $\mathcal B$ is a basis.

However, I would not suggest putting the index on top and the basis on the bottom unless you'd already been following a convention where the indices go on top. And I would strongly suggest not using $y$ (or $x$) for an index and not using adjacent letters in the alphabet in the same typeface to refer to an index and a basis.